# How to filter a tibble and turn it into a matrix?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have made a tibble with three columns. Cancer status (case/control), trait A (x1) and trait B (x2).

```
cancer <- tibble(case = factor(c(rep(1,3),rep(0,3)),
                               levels = c(0,1),
                               labels = c("control","case")),
                 x1 = c(1,2,3,4,2,3),
                 x2 = c(4,8,6,0,2,4))
```

Now I want to make a matrix with the means of x1 and x2, but just for the patients with cancer (case). So a 2x1 matrix. How can I do this? I tried to start with those two functions, but I can't get them to work...

```
matrix <- filter(cancer$case == "case")
mean(cancer$x1 & cancer$case == "case")
```

I know this is a very simple example and I could do it by hand, but I'm new to R and want to know how I could handle this with 6000 instead of 6 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
library(dplyr)
cancer %>% 
  summarise(meanx1 = mean(x1[case == "case"]),
            meanx2 = mean(x2[case == "case"]))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  meanx1 meanx2
   <dbl>  <dbl>
1      2      6
```

If you want it as a matrix:

```
cancer %>% 
  summarise(meanx1 = mean(x1[case == "case"]),
            meanx2 = mean(x2[case == "case"])) %>% 
  as.matrix()

     meanx1 meanx2
[1,]      2      6
```

And with `across` if you have updated to `dplyr` 1.0.0:

```
cancer %>% 
  summarise(across(x1:x2, ~mean(x1[case == "case"]), .names = "mean_{col}")) %>% 
  as.matrix()

     mean_x1 mean_x2
[1,]       2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new dplyr 1.0.0, you can do

```
library(tidyverse)

cancer <- tibble(case = factor(c(rep(1,3),rep(0,3)),
                               levels = c(0,1),
                               labels = c("control","case")),
                 x1 = c(1,2,3,4,2,3),
                 x2 = c(4,8,6,0,2,4))

cancer %>% 
  filter(case == "case") %>% 
  summarize(across(x1:x2, mean))
```